# Aufs Whiteout removal

Tags: filesystems, aufs

I'm using AUFS for merging 100+ branches for a project. At runtime, I frequently add or remove few branches.

Now, If I have a branch named "firefox-21.0" and If I update/modify one of it's file then AUFS creats it's whiteout file (.wh). So far so good.
But later, If I planned to update the firefox to new version then I have to delete the "firefox-21.0" branch from system. Deleting branch from AUFS is easy. But question is [how do I remove those `.wh` files created ?]

If I merge `firefox-23.0` then previously created `.wh` may get preference over old `firefox-21.0`'s file

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To delete the hidden [AUFS](http://aufs.sourceforge.net/) [white-out files](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/UnionFS), you could:

Find them, and remove them:

- `find . -regex  '.*/\.wh\.\.wh\.plnk' -delete` for `.plnk` files
- `find . -regex  '.*/\.wh\.\.wh\.aufs' -delete` for `.aufs` files

This matches (in any subfolder) the aufs-specific files `.wh ..wh.plnk` and `.wh..wh.aufs`, but would not match -say- `.wh.Fwh.aufs`

In the RegEx, '.' matches any character, while '\.' only matches the literal dot.

EDIT: Updated command to use `-delete` option after comment hint from @wodny